# Creating multiple dictionaries with parts of the file name as keys and content of the file as values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a number of CSV files each called file1_OUT.csv, file2_OUT.csv [...] file52_OUT.csv etc.
The content of the csv files looks like this:

```
| header1    | header2 |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 0.0000E+00 | ax      |
| 1.0000E+00 | ay      |
| 2.0000E+02 | bx      |
| 3.0000E+03 | by      |
| 4.0000E+03 | cx      |
| 4.0000E+01 | cy      |
| 0.0000E+00 | dx      |
| 0.0000E+00 | dy      |
```

For each file I'd like to create 8 dictionaries (ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy) which are supposed to look like these:

```
ax = {'file1': 0.0000E+00, 'file2': 5.0000E+00, 'file3': 2.0000E+00 ... }
ay = {'file1': 1.0000E+00, 'file2': 0.0000E+00, 'file3': 3.0000E+00 ... }
bx = {...}
by = {...}
...
```

The numbers in the dictionary come from the column called header1.

I am newish to python but I managed to extract the values for ax, ay etc. using this piece of code:

```
import os, re, csv, glob
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
    
for file in Path(directory).glob('*_OUT.csv'):   
        with open(file, mode='r') as inp:
            ax = df['header1'][0]
            ay = df['header1'][1]
            bx = df['header1'][2]
            by = df['header1'][3]
            cx = df['header1'][4]
            cy = df['header1'][5]
            dx = df['header1'][6]
            dy = df['header1'][7]
            print(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy)
```

Unfortunatly the srings are called ax, ay... for each file, and I guess they are overvritten in each iteration.

In addition I was able to extract the file names into a list with this piece of code:

```
files_dir =  listdir(directory)
new_list = []
for names in files_dir:
    if names.endswith("_OUT.csv"):
        new_list.append(names.strip('.csv'))
print(new_list)
```

I am not sure how useful my attempt is since I am not able to combine the ax, ay, bx... strings with the list containg file names and the dictionary the names (i.e. column two of my input csv files). Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: I would recommend to import all those csv files as SQLite tables instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your python script is in the same file directory as your csv files, you should be able to do something like this - this will return a nested dictionary structure, with "header2" as the key in each case.

```
import csv
import os

# gets current working directory of the python file - if neccessary, hard type the directory with the CSVs and replace cwd below
cwd = os.getcwd()

# list comprehension to build list of target CSV files in directory
target_files = [file for file in os.listdir(cwd) if file.endswith('csv')]

# create output dictionary
file_summaries = {}

# loop over files in target list
for filename in target_files:

    # open each file
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_in:
        # pass file to built-in csv.DictReader - returns data in list of dictionaries [{}, {}]
        file_data = csv.DictReader(file_in)

        # loop over each files' data - and set default info into file summary object
        for row in file_data:
            
            file_summaries.setdefault(row['header2'], {})
            file_summaries[row['header2']].setdefault(filename, row['header1'])


# display result
print(file_summaries)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems the code you sent is running without errors but it unfortunately only creates an empty dictionary.

Comment: im guessing you arent looping over any files ? print(target_files) to confirm you are actually processing / opening any data.

Comment: This works really well now :) Thank you so much! I created the nested dictionary using the code you suggested. Later in my code I just use "file_summaries.pop" to process the data i.e. ax, ay, bx, by etc individaully.